# How to add math equations in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am new in Highcharts. I want to add a mathematical equation in highcharts as example (y=3x+5) . How can i generate the function and pass data to highchart series.

Please help :) Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts has no implemented this kidn of solutions, but you can prepare your own function which calculate point values and prepare array with all of them (used by series).

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can generate the data to be used to plot the data before the chart is rendered. i've seen this example in highcharts demos where in they have used a function which returns the data to be plotted.

here is the js fiddle of that
http://jsfiddle.net/HHPm7/

like you said using an equation like

```
y = (3 * x) + 5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HHPm7/1/

I hope this will be useful